# How to enable EC2 Instance termination protection in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Instance.html

I cannot find anything related to it. I guess I need to use L1 construct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you will have to use the L1 construct: [`CfnInstance`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.CfnInstance.html).

This construct has the [`disableApiTermination`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.CfnInstance.html#disableapitermination) prop which can be set to `true` to enable termination protection.

> disableApiTermination?
> Type: `boolean` | `IResolvable` (optional)
>
> If you set this parameter to true , you can't terminate the instance using the Amazon EC2 console, CLI, or API; otherwise, you can.
>
> Default: `false`

Comment: It is unbelieveable that when CDK 2.0 is out and I still need to stick with L1 construct.

Comment: You can use property overrides to set a specific value. For example :
const cfnInstance = yourL2Instance.node.defaultChild as ec2.CfnInstance;
cfnInstance.addPropertyOverride("DisableApiTermination", true);
See : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html